# Getting evwn number at least once

Tags: probability

What is the least number of times a  fair die is   to be tossed so that  we get an even number at least once with probability at least .75?I know if X is the number of times we get an even number then
$$ X  \sim B(n,p)$$ where p=.5

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also, I expect you miswrote the question.  As it stands, the answer is clearly $1$.

Comment: One is enough, but what you wrote (disregarding the misspellings of "die" and "at") is probably not the right question.

Comment: Is the $.075$ supposed to be $0.75$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twice

First roll: 50% odd 50% even

Second roll: 50% odd 50% even

P(At least one even) = 1 - P(Odds in both rolls) = 1-0.5x0.5 = 0.75